# Getting the Jcrop coordinates back into Jcrop through javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jcrop

If I set a variable like this:

```
var coords = jcrop_api.tellSelect();
```

It returns my current Jcrop selections coordinates in an x,y,x2,y2,h,w format.

Now if I want to set my coordinates back to that, I could go:

```
jcrop_api.animateTo(coords)
```

But the animateTo function only takes an array of 4, [x, y, w, h]
When I try to do the above way, it eventually breaks the code. 
So how do I change my variable coords to fit this format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API functions you mention at least at the 0.9.12 version of the plugin..

jcrop_api.tellSelect() returns an object like this:

```
{
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   x2: 10,
   y2: 10,
   w: 10,
   h:10
}
```

and jcrop_api.animateTo needs one array like [x,y,x2,y2], so, try this:

```
var c = jcrop_api.tellSelect();

jcrop_api.animateTo([c.x,c.y, c.x2, c.y2]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This explains a lot. Only just started to learn javascript!